# Поддержка html + css + javascript интерфейсов

Tags: c++, framework

Существуют ли фреймоврки под C++ язык, которые позволяют использовать HTML + Javascript UI интерфейсы в своих проектах?

Comment: WebKit https://habrahabr.ru/post/244281/

Comment: @Sublihim второй вариант близок в этой статье )

Comment: Если Qt окажется слишком тяжеловесным, то sciter: http://sciter.com